I used YOLO V8 from ultralytics and I face this problem
This is the code I'm trying to run but I get an error.
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO(r"C:\Users\skahi\Downloads\runs-20240406T064851Z-001\runs\detect\train\weights\best.pt")
results = model(r"D:\datasets\A_Z Handwritten Data\testimg1.png", save=True)

The output should be the number of detection of given image.
But I get this error:
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 model(r"D:\datasets\A_Z Handwritten Data\testimg1.png", save=True)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py:169, in Model.__call__(self, source, stream, **kwargs)
    146 def __call__(
    147     self,
    148     source: Union[str, Path, int, list, tuple, np.ndarray, torch.Tensor] = None,
    149     stream: bool = False,
    150     **kwargs,
    151 ) -> list:
    152     """
    153     An alias for the predict method, enabling the model instance to be callable.
    154 
   (...)
    167         (List[ultralytics.engine.results.Results]): A list of prediction results, encapsulated in the Results class.
    168     """
--> 169     return self.predict(source, stream, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py:439, in Model.predict(self, source, stream, predictor, **kwargs)
    437 if prompts and hasattr(self.predictor, "set_prompts"):  # for SAM-type models
    438     self.predictor.set_prompts(prompts)
--> 439 return self.predictor.predict_cli(source=source) if is_cli else self.predictor(source=source, stream=stream)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py:168, in BasePredictor.__call__(self, source, model, stream, *args, **kwargs)
    166     return self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs)
    167 else:
--> 168     return list(self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs))

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py:35, in _wrap_generator.<locals>.generator_context(*args, **kwargs)
     32 try:
     33     # Issuing `None` to a generator fires it up
     34     with ctx_factory():
---> 35         response = gen.send(None)
     37     while True:
     38         try:
     39             # Forward the response to our caller and get its next request

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py:255, in BasePredictor.stream_inference(self, source, model, *args, **kwargs)
    253 # Postprocess
    254 with profilers[2]:
--> 255     self.results = self.postprocess(preds, im, im0s)
    256 self.run_callbacks("on_predict_postprocess_end")
    258 # Visualize, save, write results

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\detect\predict.py:25, in DetectionPredictor.postprocess(self, preds, img, orig_imgs)
     23 def postprocess(self, preds, img, orig_imgs):
     24     """Post-processes predictions and returns a list of Results objects."""
---> 25     preds = ops.non_max_suppression(
     26         preds,
     27         self.args.conf,
     28         self.args.iou,
     29         agnostic=self.args.agnostic_nms,
     30         max_det=self.args.max_det,
     31         classes=self.args.classes,
     32     )
     34     if not isinstance(orig_imgs, list):  # input images are a torch.Tensor, not a list
     35         orig_imgs = ops.convert_torch2numpy_batch(orig_imgs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\ops.py:282, in non_max_suppression(prediction, conf_thres, iou_thres, classes, agnostic, multi_label, labels, max_det, nc, max_time_img, max_nms, max_wh, in_place, rotated)
    280 else:
    281     boxes = x[:, :4] + c  # boxes (offset by class)
--> 282     i = torchvision.ops.nms(boxes, scores, iou_thres)  # NMS
    283 i = i[:max_det]  # limit detections
    285 # # Experimental
    286 # merge = False  # use merge-NMS
    287 # if merge and (1 < n < 3E3):  # Merge NMS (boxes merged using weighted mean)
   (...)
    294 #     if redundant:
    295 #         i = i[iou.sum(1) > 1]  # require redundancy

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\boxes.py:41, in nms(boxes, scores, iou_threshold)
     39     _log_api_usage_once(nms)
     40 _assert_has_ops()
---> 41 return torch.ops.torchvision.nms(boxes, scores, iou_threshold)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py:755, in OpOverloadPacket.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    750 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    751     # overloading __call__ to ensure torch.ops.foo.bar()
    752     # is still callable from JIT
    753     # We save the function ptr as the `op` attribute on
    754     # OpOverloadPacket to access it here.
--> 755     return self._op(*args, **(kwargs or {}))

NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'torchvision::nms' is only available for these backends: [CPU, Meta, QuantizedCPU, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy, AutogradMeta, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, BatchedNestedTensor, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PreDispatch, PythonDispatcher].

CPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\cpu\nms_kernel.cpp:112 [kernel]
Meta: registered at /dev/null:440 [kernel]
QuantizedCPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\quantized\cpu\qnms_kernel.cpp:124 [kernel]
BackendSelect: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\BackendSelectFallbackKernel.cpp:3 [backend fallback]
Python: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:154 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:498 [backend fallback]
Functionalize: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\FunctionalizeFallbackKernel.cpp:324 [backend fallback]
Named: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\NamedRegistrations.cpp:7 [backend fallback]
Conjugate: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\ConjugateFallback.cpp:17 [backend fallback]
Negative: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\native\NegateFallback.cpp:19 [backend fallback]
ZeroTensor: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\ZeroTensorFallback.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
ADInplaceOrView: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
AutogradOther: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:53 [backend fallback]
AutogradCPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:57 [backend fallback]
AutogradCUDA: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:65 [backend fallback]
AutogradXLA: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:69 [backend fallback]
AutogradMPS: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:77 [backend fallback]
AutogradXPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:61 [backend fallback]
AutogradHPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:90 [backend fallback]
AutogradLazy: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:73 [backend fallback]
AutogradMeta: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:81 [backend fallback]
Tracer: registered at ..\torch\csrc\autograd\TraceTypeManual.cpp:297 [backend fallback]
AutocastCPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\autocast\nms_kernel.cpp:34 [kernel]
AutocastCUDA: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\autocast\nms_kernel.cpp:27 [kernel]
FuncTorchBatched: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:720 [backend fallback]
BatchedNestedTensor: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:746 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchVmapMode: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:28 [backend fallback]
Batched: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:1075 [backend fallback]
VmapMode: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:33 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchGradWrapper: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\TensorWrapper.cpp:203 [backend fallback]
PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:162 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:494 [backend fallback]
PreDispatch: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:166 [backend fallback]
PythonDispatcher: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:158 [backend fallback]

​

It looks like an environment problem, there is an open issue on github with some tips on how to avoid it. The main idea is to install the valid version of torchvision with CUDA support: github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/8296. You can find some more open issues with the similar problem

As mentionned by @hanna_liavoshka,
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend

is indicating that the NMS operation (Non-maximum suppresion) operation from torchvision are not properly configured to use CUDA. Ensure that you have in your environment a torchvision with CUDA support.
